# How can I edit point in UIBezierPath on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, quartz-graphics, uibezierpath

I am building a drawing application (something like [MiniDraw](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/minidraw-lite-vector-graphics/id355567916?mt=8)).
[UIBezierPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) class is cool for that and I can accomplis dynamic path building:

```
[path addCurve:23.0 controlPoint:5.5]; //etc...
```

When I finish I want the ability to change the points in that path without creating a new UIBezierPath, that way I could accomplish dynamic editing of path.

For example, [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/) javascript library can do this in a way that each path object contains array structure like this:

```
[['M', 20, 20], ['L', 40, 40], ['Q', 70, 50, 30], ['Z']] //etc...
```

That way I can edit each point but I don't see anything similar in UIBezierPath class.

Comment: You cannot directly access (for editability) the point data of a UIBezierPath object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIBezierPath` does not allow your to change points already added to the path.  You will have to create a new path.

Comment: So that means that I wold have to create a new path for every touch move event when I am editing some path? That's not good at all.

Comment: If you are writing an app with serious vector drawing/editing capabilities, you'll want to create your own class for storing an editable path.